# tcl script to extract the Warnings and occurances

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to write tcl script that open a file and find out Error/Warning and occurances in that.

For example, in file, I have something like:

```
Severity: Warning    Occurrence: 2
```

or

```
Severity: Error    Occurrence: 2
```

I want to extract this information

```
      set fp [ open xx/a.rpt "r" ]
       set Error  "--"
        set Warning "--"
            while { [ gets $fp line ] >= 0 } {
               if { [ regexp "^# Error" $line ] } {
                  regsub -all {(\s+)} $line { } temp_err
                  set Error  [ lindex [ split $temp_err " " ] 2 ]
                  puts $Error
               } elseif { 
                  [ regexp "^# Warning" $line ] 
               } 
               {
                  regsub -all {(\s+)} $line { } temp_warn
                  set Warning [ lindex [ split $temp_warn " " ] 2 ]
                  puts $Warning             
               }

            };
        close $fp
```

Comment: Why do you have a `#` in your regexes ?

Answer (score 0):

For matching warnings:

```
 ^Severity:\s+Warning\s+Occurrence:\s+\d+
```

For matching errors:

```
 ^Severity:\s+Error\s+Occurrence:\s+\d+
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.If I have multiple time Error ,in the end I want total occurances.For Example in file I have Error Occurnace 2 and then some other error occurance 6 ,in the end I want Error total to be 8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you left a few details out of your question.  (Bad idea; you get incomplete answers that way.)  From the fact that you have the regsub construct below, I'm guessing that there's an error name in your input that you want to store.  And your comment to Alex says you want to capture the count of occurrences.

There's a part of regexp that extracts information as it compares, using parentheses ().  Based on the snipped you provided in the comment, build your regexp like this:

```
if { [regexp {^([^:\s]):.+Severity:\s+Error\s+Occurrence:\s+(\d+)} $line match errName count] } {
    puts $errName
    incr errCount $count
}
```

The first set of parentheses around [^:\s]+ should collect the chunk of non-whitespace before the first colon, and place it in the variable "errName".  The second set around \d+ should collect the digits that end the line and put them in the variable "count".

The principle of collecting your subfields with parentheses is powerful, and way more efficient than the regsub/split/lindex processing you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Erik.I am sorry for not giving detailed explanation.You are right .I have error name as well.For example ,here is the snippet of my report                                                  error_name: xxxxxxxxxx                                      Severity: Warning    Occurrence: 2
error_name2:xxxxxxxxxxx.
    Severity: Warning    Occurrence: 16
error_name3:xxxxxxxxxxxxx                                            Severity: Warning    Occurrence: 15

Comment: No worries.  regexps in particular are picky about details, so we have to be picky in our answers.

Comment: In my example report there is error name in first line and in second line no and type (warning/error) ,so as per your suggestion it will extact the type and number .right? The name of error will differ everytime ,Is there way to extract the name as well ?

Comment: I've just edited my suggestion based on your pattern.  Give it a look and see how it does for you.

Comment: Give it a try.  I just made another tiny edit (added .+ between the first : and "Severity" to soak up the error description), so try the new version.

Comment: I tried .It gives error invalid command name "^:s"
    while executing
"^:\s"
    ("while" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"while { [ gets $fp line ] >= 0 } {
if { [regexp "^([^:\s]):.+Severity:\s+Error\s+Occurrence:\s+(\d+)" $line match errName count] } {
    puts $errName..."

Comment: i WAS ABLE TO GET RID OF ERROR ,BUT IT DOES NOT O/P ANYTHING

Comment: @tcluser16 That was due to a classic mistake; not putting the RE in braces (so backslashes and brackets get parsed as Tcl syntax). While it's too strong to say that you should _always_ brace REs in Tcl, it's a very good practice that you ought to follow unless you've got a strong reason to do otherwise (like substituting a sub-RE into a larger one).